# Moodle web services refresh token

Tags: rest, web-services, moodle

I understand that i can fetch web services client token through the url

https://www.yourmoodle.com/login/token.php?username=USERNAME&password=PASSWORD&service=SERVICESHORTNAME

and it works. I am getting a token and private token.

but i do not see a refreshtoken url. I can see the expiry date through moodle admin account.

Does anyone how to refresh moodle token?
what is the use of private token?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there's no inbuilt functionality to refresh a token like the OAuth 2 spec. You would need to call the login/token.php again if your API call fails.

Unfortunately the login/token.php file only returns the **token** and may return the **private token** (Private token, only transmitted to https sites and non-admin users.). From the client's perspective there's no way to know when the token will expire.

References:

- https://github.com/moodle/moodle/blob/master/login/token.php
- https://github.com/moodle/moodle/blob/master/lib/externallib.php#L1034

Comment: Thanks for the info @Emilio . Do you know what is the use of private token?

Comment: @koushikv have you found the use of the private token? messing with this too now... :/

Comment: sorry, never did :(